# How to size track width for AC application

Tags: current, pcb-design, relay, trace

I want to run AC volatge through my relay shown below:

[image]

My track width is 2mm for the COM, N/O, and N/C pins. These tracks go from the relay to the 3-pin connector. The relay (G5LE-14-12DC) is found [enter link description here](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5le.pdf).

**My question:**

How do I size the track width (track width for the COM, N/O, and N/C pins to the 3-pin connector) for the maximum rating of this relay for AC (230V AC) application?

Comment: Track width depends on current, which you haven’t specified. Track _spacing_ on the other hand is set by safety standards you need to adhere to.

Comment: @winny current was the maximum for rated current this relay can handle which is 10A (resistive load worse case).

Comment: @winny where do I find these standards for the spacing?

Comment: Please edit that into the body of the question. Creepage and clearance is defined by UL/IEC 60950.

Answer (score 1):

**Track width**, in this specific case where impedance control is not needed, must guarantee a smaller enough resistance to the trace.
This can be calculated in function of current, here you can set up for your specifications [Trace width calculator](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-pcb-trace-width)

As an example with **1 A**

> 25 °C Ambient temperature
> 1 mm thickness
> 50 mm trace length
> 1 °C allowed temperature increment

You need at least *0.04 mm* trace width